# Apache 2.4: application.com also at domain.com/application, how?

Tags: php, apache, dns, alias

I have an application that lives at "application.com" and I need to be able to access it from "domain.com/application", with the URL also updating depending on how the application is accessed. How would I do this? I've been trying to use the alias directive and it seems to half-way get me there but I'm definitely missing *something*, I just don't know what. Could someone point me in the right direction with this? Thanks a lot.

Apache: 2.4
PHP 5.6

Comment: Couldn't you just redirect from domain.com/application to application.com  ?

Comment: I'd be open to any solution, I'm just not particularly adept at Apache rewrites and such. The tldr version of what I need is to have website.com/app load application.com while maintaining the URL. Not redirecting to application.com but loading application.com inside website.com/app.